# Question about plotting

Tags: plotting, homework

I would like to duplicate this graph:

[image]

I've used this code to draw the circle:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 3, {-2Pi, 2Pi}]},PointSize[.025]]
```

But *Mathematica* complains about improperly formatted options, and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Andrea, your problem was that you put the `PointSize` out of place. This works: `Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Circle[{0, 0}, 3, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}]}]`. Your question was put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error) and is unlikely to help any future visitors as it answer is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 7):

```
Graphics[{{Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}]}, {Red, 
  Line[{{1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}]}, {Line[{{0, 1/Sqrt[2]},
    {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}]}, {Green, PointSize[.03], 
  Point[{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}]}}, 
  Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I added a picture & fixed formatting, I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Öskå that is ok. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Such plane figures are amenable to using complex numbers instead of pairs of reals for their points, and hence readily drawn using David Park's *Presentations* add-on (http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html):

```
Draw2D[{
   ComplexCircle[0, 1],
   Green, 
   ComplexLine[{0, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}], PointSize[0.025], ComplexPoint[(1 + I)/Sqrt[2]],
   Red, 
   ComplexLine[{1/Sqrt[2], (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}], ComplexLine[{I/Sqrt[2], (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}]
   },
   Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{1/Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2]}}]
```

[image]